# Can somebody explain this delay routine written in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86, logic, tasm, microprocessors

I have this delay routine in assembly language, can anybody explain me how this works?
I'm very much new to assembly and trying to understand the insights. Can anybody help me understand the functionality of PUSH & POP? Any help will be appreciated :)

```
    DELAY: MOV CX, 0FFH

    DLY5: PUSH CX
          MOV CX, 03FFH

    DLY10: NOP
           LOOP DLY10
           POP CX
           LOOP DLY5
           RET
```

Comment: `CX` is used as a loop counter. So you're doing 0x100 * 0x400 rounds of no-ops.

Comment: Yes I know that. But What's the flow of execution of these instructions?

Comment: `LOOP` decrements `CX` and jumps to the given label unless `CX` becomes zero. If you Google "x86 loop instruction" or "x86 instruction set" you will find lots of helpful information on x86 instructions.

Comment: Yes I understood that:) But I'm not able to understand the functionality of PUSH & POP..

Comment: Do you know C? It's the equivalent of `for (int i = 0; i != 0x100; ++i) { for (int k = 0; k != 0x400; ++k) { (volatile void)0; } }` Think about how you access the counters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `push/pop` in this case serves to run the outer loop. and only use one register for the whole delay, while having two counters (inner loop with 03FFH and outer loop with 0FFH).

Maybe the author didn't want to spoil another register, or he wanted to use the loop instruction which requires the `cx` register.

Comment: It would be nice to either flag the answer or at least increase the marker. :)